# Spring Security: Why .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**").permitAll() is not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm struggling to access the `/api/v1/web/**` URIs using no JWT token. This URI has to be public. I know this is a common feature in many applications, otherwise, how could we create sign in, sign on and reset password pages? So, I'm sure I'm making some silly mistake as I've not much experience with Spring Boot / Security.

Here is my web security config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
}

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     // disable caching
         http.headers().cacheControl();

         /*ROUTING SECURITY*/
     http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
         .cors()
         .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**").permitAll()

             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/users/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("USERS_LIST,USERS_CREATE,USERS_EDIT,USERS_DELETE")
             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/locals/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("LOCALS_LIST,LOCALS_CREATE,LOCALS_EDIT,LOCALS_DELETE")
             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/utils/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("UTILS")

         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         // We filter the api/login requests
         .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/v1/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
         // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
         .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 }

 //     @Override
 //     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
 //         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**");
 //     }
 }
```

Here is my TokenAuthentication:

```
 public class TokenAuthenticationService {

 private final String secret = "secret_string";
 private final String tokenPrefix = "Bearer ";
 private final String headerString = "Authorization";

 public void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {

     GregorianCalendar expiration = new GregorianCalendar();
     expiration.add(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
     //expiration.add(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 10);

     List<UserAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<UserAuthority>();
     for( GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities() ) {
         authorities.add( new UserAuthority( authority.getAuthority() ) );
     }

     AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser = new AuthenticatedUser( (String)authentication.getPrincipal(), authorities );
     String dataToGenerateToken;
    try {
        dataToGenerateToken = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString( authenticatedUser );
         // We generate a token now
         String generatedToken = Jwts.builder()
             .setSubject( dataToGenerateToken )
             .setExpiration( expiration.getTime() )
             .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
             .compact();
         response.addHeader(headerString, tokenPrefix + generatedToken);
         response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
         response.getWriter().write( dataToGenerateToken );
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
 }

 public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
     String token = request.getHeader(headerString).substring(7);
     if (token != null) {
         // parse the token.
         String userData = Jwts.parser()
             .setSigningKey(secret)
             .parseClaimsJws(token)
             .getBody()
             .getSubject();
         if (userData != null) // we managed to retrieve a user
         {
             AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser;
            try {
                authenticatedUser = new ObjectMapper().readValue(userData, AuthenticatedUser.class);
                return authenticatedUser;
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
 }
```

I only can access `/api/v1/web/**` if I include the JWT authentication, if not I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at br.com.bilheteriarapida.admin.security.jwt.TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationService.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
at br.com.bilheteriarapida.admin.security.jwt.JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
```

And if I remove the comments of this code:

```
//     @Override
//     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
//         web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**");
//     }
```

I can only execute SELECT queries under `/api/v1/web/**` URIs, if I try to call a service which saves an object (UPDATE or INSERT) I get a Transactional error. Very weird, I know.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What is line 61? Is it `String token = request.getHeader(headerString).substring(7);`? You can't call `substring` on `null`.

Comment: The last error was that @dur. I can not believe :( At least now I could configure the security properly, using `antMatchers()` and I don't need to use the `web.ignoring()` anymore. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please accept the duplicate. It is really just a `NullPointerException`. That question has no value for other users. There is no harm for you, because your question is upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

With the SO guys help, I could realize what I was doing wrong and here is my final solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
}

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     // disable caching
         http.headers().cacheControl();

         /*ROUTING SECURITY*/
     http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
         .cors()
         .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/api/v1/web/**").permitAll()
         .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/users/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("USERS_LIST,USERS_CREATE,USERS_EDIT,USERS_DELETE")
             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/locals/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("LOCALS_LIST,LOCALS_CREATE,LOCALS_EDIT,LOCALS_DELETE")
             .antMatchers( "/api/v1/utils/**" ).hasAnyAuthority("UTILS")
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
             .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/v1/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
             .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      }     
 }
```

and in the `TokenAuthenticationService` class, I edited the getAuthentication method first lines to:

```
 public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
 String token = request.getHeader(headerString);
 if (token != null) {
     token = token.substring(7);
 ....
```

}

Now, my application is well configured to access public and private URIs properly. No needing `web.ignoring()` anymore.